# PHP Server Side Script for C# BackgroundUploader

Tags: c#, php, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I try to upload a file using the [BackgroundTrasfer Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61/) to an Apache server.
The problem is I can not find the server side PHP script which works with php://input instead of enctype="multipart/form-data".

A PHP developer says change your C#. A C# developer says change you PHP. I am desperate. I am sure I am not the fist who tries to upload a file from windows app to an Apache server without ASP. Finally it should be a standard script.

Finally I have to translate this ASPX script into PHP

```
string fileName = Request.Headers["Filename"];
Response.Write("Filename is " + fileName);

string saveLocation = Server.MapPath("Data") + "\\" + fileName;
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(saveLocation, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
{
    Request.InputStream.CopyTo(fs);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean: ,,i cannot find the server side PHP script which works with php://input'' ?

Comment: I mean the web is full of samples for a simple multipart/form-data uploads. And on the server side you can actually just copy and past the script and it works. But I can not find samples für an upload without multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 1):

```
$handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
while (!feof($handle)) {
   $contents = fread($handle, 1024*1024); //Read by 1mb
   file_put_contents('file.bin', $contents, FILE_APPEND);
}
fclose($handle);
```

This is just an EXAMPLE, it lacks verification and so on!!! but it should give you some understanding in the way of reading file.

Here you can write a bit more about it (its commonly used when using PUT method): http://php.net/manual/pl/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer but the fwrite part is missing in you example or not? After following you link I get always a 0 byte file and can I get the original file name?

Comment: I used file_put_contents instead.

Comment: `file_put_contents` is not part of the HTTP PUT method. It is simply a built in PHP method to write data to a file. I suggest you read up on programming. Seti's answer would do what you need. http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: So i will explain.
fopen - opens the stream (here stream of ,,raw'' data). php:///input is OFTEN used with HTTP PUT method, as then php://input contains ONLY file stream.
Then until stream ends use $contents to fread 1mb (max) of data.  And then use ATOMIC file_put_contents function to write the file (append) with read data. So o dont need to open/close target file within the code - therefore making it easier to read.
Then close.

Comment: And it really doesnt matter if you use PUT/POST - but i told you about PUT so you can find out more about using php://input as its common there.

Comment: I am very grateful for your help. It looks right and I get 200 and no errors on the client side but finally I have a 0 byte file on the server. Same if I use example given here http://php.net/manual/pl/features.file-upload.put-method.php